# Setup method not getting called in Hadoop Mapper

Tags: java, join, hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

I run a sequence of Hadoop Mapper/Reducers and get a list of Movie IDs. I use a MovieData file to display the names of the movies based on these IDs. I'm using a Mapper class as below. I see that setUp method is not getting called because I din't see the print statement and also I get a Null Exception when I try to use this HashMap loaded in the load method. Following is the code. Any pointers are appreciated.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.hadoop.filecache.DistributedCache;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context;

public class MovieNamesMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {

    private static HashMap<String, String> movieNameHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private String movieId = "";

    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("Setting up system..");

        Path[] cacheFilesLocal = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context
                .getConfiguration());

        for (Path eachPath : cacheFilesLocal) {
            if (eachPath.getName().toString().trim().equals("u.item")) {
                loadMovieNamesHashMap(eachPath, context);
            }
        }

    }

    private void loadMovieNamesHashMap(Path filePath, Context context)
            throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Loading movie names..");

        String strLineRead = "";

        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    filePath.toString()));

            while ((strLineRead = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String movieIdArray[] = strLineRead.toString().split("\t|::");
                movieNameHashMap.put(movieIdArray[0].trim(),
                        movieIdArray[1].trim());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                bufferedReader.close();

            }

        }

    }

    public void map(Object key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output,
            Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(key.toString() + " - " + value.toString());
        if (value.toString().length() > 0) {
            String moviePairArray[] = value.toString().split(":");

            for (String moviePair : moviePairArray) {
                String movieArray[] = moviePair.split(",");
                output.collect(new Text(movieNameHashMap.get(movieArray[0])),
                        new Text(movieNameHashMap.get(movieArray[1])));
            }
        }

    }

    public String getMovieId() {
        return movieId;
    }

    public void setMovieId(String movieId) {
        this.movieId = movieId;
    }

}
```

Following is my run method.

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // For finding user and his rated movie list.
    JobConf conf1 = new JobConf(MovieTopDriver.class);
    conf1.setMapperClass(MoviePairsMapper.class);
    conf1.setReducerClass(MoviePairsReducer.class);

    conf1.setJarByClass(MovieTopDriver.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf1, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf1, new Path("temp"));

    conf1.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf1.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    conf1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf1.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    // For finding movie pairs.
    JobConf conf2 = new JobConf(MovieTopDriver.class);
    conf2.setMapperClass(MoviePairsCoOccurMapper.class);
    conf2.setReducerClass(MoviePairsCoOccurReducer.class);

    conf2.setJarByClass(MovieTopDriver.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf2, new Path("temp"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf2, new Path("freq_temp"));

    conf2.setInputFormat(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);

    conf2.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf2.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    conf2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf2.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    // Find top frequent movies along with their names.
    // Output Freq, moviePair
    // Keep a count and output only 20.

    JobConf conf3 = new JobConf(MovieTopDriver.class);
    conf3.setMapperClass(ValueKeyMapper.class);
    conf3.setReducerClass(ValueKeyReducer.class);

    conf3.setJarByClass(MovieTopDriver.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf3, new Path("freq_temp"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf3, new Path("freq_temp2"));

    conf3.setInputFormat(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
    conf3.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    conf3.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    conf3.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    conf3.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    // Use only one reducer as we want to sort.
    conf3.setNumReduceTasks(1);

    // To sort in decreasing order.
    conf3.setOutputKeyComparatorClass(LongWritable.DecreasingComparator.class);

    // Find top movie name
    // Use a mapper side join to output names.

    JobConf conf4 = new JobConf(MovieTopDriver.class);
    conf4.setMapperClass(MovieNamesMapper.class);
    conf4.setJarByClass(MovieTopDriver.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf4, new Path("freq_temp2"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf4, new Path(args[1]));

    conf4.setInputFormat(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
    conf4.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf4.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    // Run the jobs

    Job job1 = new Job(conf1);
    Job job2 = new Job(conf2);
    Job job3 = new Job(conf3);
    Job job4 = new Job(conf4);

    JobControl jobControl = new JobControl("jobControl");
    jobControl.addJob(job1);
    jobControl.addJob(job2);
    jobControl.addJob(job3);
    jobControl.addJob(job4);
    job2.addDependingJob(job1);
    job3.addDependingJob(job2);
    job4.addDependingJob(job3);
    handleRun(jobControl);

    FileSystem.get(conf2).deleteOnExit(new Path("temp"));
    FileSystem.get(conf3).deleteOnExit(new Path("freq_temp"));
    FileSystem.get(conf4).deleteOnExit(new Path("freq_temp2"));

    System.out.println("Program complete.");
    return 0;
}
```

**Update:** I'm using Hadoop 1.2.1 and I can use only that as I'm using a cluster in school.

**Update** : Used configure instead of setup but it still doesn't get called.

```
public void configure(JobConf jobConf) {

    System.out.println("Setting up system..");

    Path[] cacheFilesLocal;
    try {
        cacheFilesLocal = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(jobConf);

        for (Path eachPath : cacheFilesLocal) {
            if (eachPath.getName().toString().trim().equals("u.item")) {

                loadMovieNamesHashMap(eachPath);

            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Added following in run method.

```
DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(new Path("moviedata"), conf4);
conf4.set("mapred.job.tracker", "local");
```

Comment: I get this warning in java for Context: Mapper.Context is a raw type. References to generic type Mapper<KEYIN,VALUEIN,KEYOUT,VALUEOUT>.Context should be parameterized.  I'm not extending Mapper instead implementing Mapper. Does that cause any problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If your IDE supports it, have your IDE override methods from super classes (in Eclipse it's Source -> Override/Implement methods) to see if the IDE thinks you got the type (Context) wrong.  If you got it wrong then Eclipse will let you override the method, inserting a stub with the correct signature.

To be precise, you need to decide whether you're using the mapred (old) or map reduce (new) packages. You seem to be using the mapred packages (note that Context is imported from the wrong package). If you want to use mapred package, use the configure() method, otherwise use setup() for the mapreduce package

Comment: I'm using hadoop 1.2.1. So, I'm unsure configure or setup but I will take a look as per documentation. Thank you for pointing.

Comment: Even that does not have setup(): http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Mapper.html

Comment: @Vencat The Mapper class does have setup().  I always use it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the configure method:

```
public void configure(JobConf job) {

   }
```

Setup is not defined in [Documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Mapper.html)

Comment: Venkat, Thank you. Sorry for not mentioning, I'm using Hadoop 1.2.1

Comment: I used configure but it still doesn't seem to be calling it. I updated the post with new code.

Comment: I fixed this by using Configure method and using DistributedCache in run method.

Answer (score 0):

--- ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION ---

I still have not been able to figure that out either. It seems that the model of calling a setup method at the beginning of the mapper, before any map calls, might only be a part of the new API ([mapred](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Mapper.html) vs [mapreduce](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html)).

I wanted to use the same map method for multiple mappers that only have a single variable difference. 
Cannot override a variable, so I call a `pulic void setup()` at the start of the map method, the overrode that in child mappers. Sure it get called with every map call (e.g. every line in the input files for these mappers), but that is the least inefficient of my inefficiencies at the moment.

```
public static class Mapper1
    extends MapReduceBase
    implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>
{
    protected int someVar;

    public void setup()
    {
        System.out.println("[LOG] setup called");
        someVar = 1;
    }

    public void map(
        LongWritable key,
        Text value,
        OutputCollector<Text, Text> output,
        Reporter reporter
    ) throws IOException
    {
        setup();
        System.out.println("someVar: " + String.valueOf(someVar));
        //...
        output.collect(someKey, someValue);
    }
}

public static class Mapper3
    extends Mapper1
{
    //protected int someVar;
    //private int someVar;

    /*
    @Override
    public void setup(Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("[LOG] setup called");
        someVar = 2;
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(JobConf jobConf)
    {
        System.out.println("[LOG] configure called");
        someVar = 2;
    }
    */
    @Override
    public void setup()
    {
        System.out.println("[LOG] setup called");
        someVar = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: @[AndrewCounts](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2495283/andrew-counts), @[AlexeyMalev](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2667872/alexey-malev). This is a solution to running a 'setup' like method in the 1.2.1 Hadoop API. I just assume that it is not the best solution someone could come up with. Honestly, the best solution is probably to upgrade to version 2. Sometimes you just need something that works for your current application and environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have a code running on Hadoop 1.2.1 (also tested on 2.2.0) that uses setup extensively. This is how it looks like in my code:

```
    @Override
    public void setup(Context context) throws IllegalArgumentException, IOException {
        logger.debug("setup has been called");
    }
```

The difference I see is using "public" instead of "protected" and also using @Override that should help you figure out if you are not properly overriding the method. Also note that I am using the new API (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce).